# Fourier series of a periodic odd function

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Given $\ f(\theta)=\theta(\pi-\theta)$ is a $2\pi$-periodic odd function on $[0,\pi]$. Compute the Fourier coefficients of $f$, and show that $\ f(\theta)=\frac{8}{\pi} \sum_{\text{$k$ odd} \ \geq 1} \frac{\sin{k\theta}}{k^3}$.

**My progress:** By applying the formula to calculate the n-th Fourier coefficient, we have:

If $n\neq 0$, $\ \hat{f}(n)= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} \theta(\pi-\theta)e^{-2in\theta}d\theta = \int_{0}^{\pi} \theta\ e^{-2in\theta}d\theta -\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} \theta^{2}e^{-2in\theta}d\theta$

Now, using integration by parts, together with the fact that $\ e^{-2in\pi}=1$, I ended up with the first integral $= -\frac{\pi}{2in}$, while the 2nd term (so including the term $\frac{-1}{\pi}$) = $\frac{-1}{2n^2} + \frac{\pi}{2in}$.

For $n=0$, I got $\hat{f}(0)= \frac{\pi^2}{6}$. Combining these results, I don't understand how can $\ f(\theta) = \text{the RHS}$ as we are asked to show:P Can anyone please help me with this problem?

**2nd progress:** I tried calculating the integral above where the exponential in the integrand is $e^{-in\theta}$ (so, 2 is deleted). And I obtained $\ \hat{f}(n)=\frac{-e^{-in\pi}}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{2e^{-in\pi}}{n^3i\pi} + \frac{2}{n^3i\pi}$ = $\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{2(-1)^{n}}{n^3i\pi}+\frac{2}{n^3i\pi}.$ Still can't get the RHS(!?)

**3rd progress:** Finally, I was able to obtain the RHS!! But I am not quite satisfied with my solution, because I have to "borrow" a result which states that if $f$ is a $2\pi$-periodic odd function, then $\ f(\theta) = 2i\ \hat{f}(n)sin(nx)$ for every ODD $n$, and using the final result in **2nd progress**, I finally got the RHS! I really want to see a solution using a purely algebraic manipulation, starting from my result for $\ \hat{f}(n)$ in **2nd progress,** without using any sorts of extra result like I did.

Comment: @Angelo: I calculated the Fourier coefficients for the Fourier sine and cosine series, using the familiar formulas shown by Angelo below, and got the final result: $a_n= \frac{8}{\pi n^3}$ for n odd (and 0 for n even), $a_0 = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ and $b_n = \frac{-4}{n^2}$ for n even (and 0 for n odd). This is reasonable, since a half-range Fourier series always have 2 distinct representations (1 in terms of cosine only, and 1 in terms of sine only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(We replace $\theta$ throughout by $x$.) Let's look at the full Fourier series of $f(x) = x(\pi-x)$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ first, where $f$ is defined outside of this interval by periodicity, i.e., $f$ is of period $2\pi$ outside $[-\pi,\pi]$.  In this case $\displaystyle a_0 = \frac{1}{\pi}\,\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\,x(\pi-x)\, dx = -\frac{2\pi^2}{3},$ where the first term (constant term) of the FS is given by $\displaystyle \frac{a_0}{2} = -\frac{\pi^2}{3}$.

Next the cosine terms are given by $\displaystyle a_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\,\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\,x(\pi-x)\,\cos (nx)\, dx = \frac{4\,(-1)^{1+n}}{n^2} .$ Similarly, the Fourier sine coefficients are given by  $\displaystyle b_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\,\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\,x(\pi-x)\,\sin (nx)\, dx =  \frac{2\pi (-1)^{n+1}}{n}.$ Hence the full FS of $f$ defined above is
$$f(x) \sim -\frac{\pi^2}{3} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left (\frac{4\,(-1)^{1+n}}{n^2}\,\cos(nx) + \frac{2\pi (-1)^{n+1}}{n}\,\sin (nx)\right),$$ for $x \in (-\pi,\pi)$ with ordinary convergence at all points of continuity. Thus, for example, setting $x=\pi/2$ we get the neat result $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{12}.$ So, this must be the correct representation.

Now for half-range expansions. In this case we are given $f(x)$ on only  {\it half the range}, i.e., $[0,\pi]$ here (instead of $[-\pi,\pi]$). But we are also told that it is $2\pi$-periodic. So the natural way to extend this function $f$ defined on $[0,\pi]$ to a periodic function of period $2\pi$ is to extend it to the left of $x=0$ by making either an even function (so you get only a cosine series) or an odd function (so you get only a sine series). To make $f$ into an even (resp. odd) function on $[-\pi,\pi]$ you redefine it by setting $f(x) = f(-x)$ (resp. $f(x) = - f(-x)$) for any $x \in [-\pi,0]$. In this case the Fourier coefficients are given by either
$\displaystyle b_n = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi x(\pi-x) \sin(nx)\, dx $ which is the original required expression for a pure sine series, and 
$\displaystyle a_n = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi x(\pi-x) \cos(nx)\, dx = -\frac{2}{n^2}(1+(-1)^n)$ with $\displaystyle a_0 = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi x(\pi-x) \, dx = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ for a pure cosine representation each series converging on $[0,\pi]$.

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier sine coefficients should be given by a formula of the form $b_n = \frac{2}{\pi}\,\int_0^{\pi} \, \theta(\pi - \theta)\, \sin (n\theta) \, d\theta = \frac{8}{\pi\,n^3}$ for $n$ odd (and $0$ for $n$ even). The stated formula now follows.

The factor of $2$ comes from the fact that we have an odd extension of $f$ to $[-\pi,\pi]$ so that the integrand becomes even thereby doubling the usual integral over $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! However, I really wonder what went wrong with my straightforward solutions above? Because if I calculated everything above correctly (I re-checked it several times, and couldn't see where I did wrong), I should have obtained a correct $f$ by multiplying each term with $e^{2inx}=cos(2nx)+sin(2nx)$, but nothing suggested me that it will give the RHS correctly. Can you please help by trying to do a straightforward calculations above?

Comment: In fact, the way I calculated the Fourier coefficients is exactly the same as the way you calculated each sine and cosine coefficients, but you got the right one:P

Comment: I think it's the extra factor of $2$ in the exponential in the Fourier coefficients. The FS of an odd periodic function should contain only sine terms but yours would also contain cosine terms.

Comment: The 2 is correct based on the general formula for calculating Fourier coefficients (see here under Definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Fourier_series_on_a_general_interval_.5Ba.2C.C2.A0b.5D). It's so weird to me that I got a completely strange result:P Can you give it a try if you have time?

Comment: If you set $P=2\pi$ in the wiki article you mentioned then you won't get a $2$ in the exponent and your FS will contain terms of the form $\sin (nx)$, not $\sin (2nx)$ like the ones above. It depends on the approach, on how you write down the period, either as $P$ or $2P$.

Comment: I think $P = \pi$ in my case because the length of the interval is $[0,\pi]$. But if so, why my Fourier coefficients is completely off:P When multiplying each term by $e^{in\theta}$ and sum them up to obtain $f$, I got both cosine and sine with the imaginary doesn't cancel:P

Comment: I see, but you are given that the period is $2\pi$ so the $P$ term in the wiki page, which defines the period, should be $2\pi$ not $\pi$.

Comment: I re-read it, but $P$ is the length of the interval where the function $f$ is integrable (it doesn't say $P$ defines the period though). Shouldn't it be $\pi$ then?

Answer (score 0):

It's implicit that the period is $P$ as you can gather from the partial sums of the FS (read line 2 under "Definition").

The important thing here is that the Fourier coefficients are always defined by integrating over a symmetric interval of length $P$, the period of $f$. Here you are looking for a so-called "half range expansion", so you need to extend the function to $[-\pi,0]$ by making it an odd function (or else the expansion you seek will not be possible). So, basically, generally speaking, the $b_n$ are given by $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)\,\sin (nx)\, dx$ where $f(x)$ is defined on $[-\pi,0]$ by a central reflection (so it becomes odd on $[-\pi,\pi]$). Since the product of two odd functions is even you get the factor of $2$ above over the half-range $[0,\pi]$.

The wiki entry should be updated.

Comment: Thank you for your insight! But in the book by Stein (Intro. to Fourier Analysis), he gave a very general formula like this: Let f be a $2\pi$- periodic Riemann integrable defined on $R$. The Fourier series for function $f$ is: $\ f(\theta) ~ \hat{f}(0) + \sum_{n\geq 1} [\hat{f}(n)+\hat{f}(-n)]\cos{n\theta} + i[\hat{f}(n)-\hat{f}(-n)]\sin{n\theta}$. In addition, if $f$ is odd, then $\hat{f}(n)=-\hat{f}(n)$, and we get a sine series. By using this formula with $\hat{f}(n)$ as shown in 3rd progress, I was able to obtain the RHS.

Comment: However, $\hat{f}(n)$ above is equal to $\frac{-2}{n^2}$ with n even, and $\frac{4}{in^3\pi}$ with $n$ odd. So this is what I didn't see the theorem given in the book holds, because $\hat{f}(n)= -\hat{f}(n)$ only with $n$ is odd. If you notice, $\hat{f}(n) + \hat{f}(-n) = \frac{-4}{n^2}$ for n is even, and $0$ for n is odd. This is also the Fourier cosine coefficient, but I'm not sure if this is correct?

Comment: See here (the #4-#6 posts): http://mathhelpboards.com/calculus-10/sine-fourier-series-coefficient-fourier-series-251.html. I don't understand how he was able to jump from #5 to #6 though.

Comment: sorry in the first comment, it should have an approximate sign between $f(\theta)$ and $\hat{f}(0)$, and $\hat{f}(n)=-\hat{f}(-n)$.

Comment: Maybe you should put less emphasis on what books say. At first I would suggest you convince yourself of the formula for the Fourier coefficients of a general Fourier series. Then, and only then, can you get the right answer for your problem. Jumping from one book to another is not always helpful as this area of FS is full of people making sometimes unclear assumptions that dumbfound students and instructors as well.

Comment: I'm convinced with your formula above already:) But just to be certain: can you show me the Fourier cosine coefficients, both $a_0$ and $a_n$? Since I got $a_0 = \frac{\pi}{6}$, which is correct, while I got $a_{n} = \frac{-2}{n^2}$, which is slightly incorrect (the correct one is $\frac{-2(-1)^n}{n^2}$). I think the point that confused me were I used a general formulas shown in the book/Wiki, but the results turned out not match with the separate formulas for sine/cosine coefficients, so I want to see where the discrepancy comes from.

Comment: Btw, I meant $a_{n}=\frac{-2}{n^2}$ for n even only (=0 when n is odd), so there was a discrepancy here. I want to figure out why, so please help!